# chromedriver on Raspbian "Exec format error"

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, raspbian

I'm having a similar issue with the "Exec format error" using chromedriver and need some help please.

- **OS**

  pi-04@raspberrypi:/usr/bin $ cat /etc/os-release
  PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
  NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
  VERSION_ID="11"
  VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
  Chromium browser Chromium 113.0.5672.95 Built on Raspbian , running on Raspbian 11

as that's the most recent version of Chromium i believe I need to install the corresponding chromedriver ie v113

To do this I've executed the following commands:

```
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/113.0.5672.63/
chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/chromedriver
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

but when I run chromedriver --version i get the error: **bash: /usr/bin/chromedriver: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error**

any ideas?